# jQuery function shows error

Tags: jquery, masonry

The following shows the this error...

```
TypeError: $container.picsLoaded is not a function
```

How to get around this?

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('.site');
$(window).load(function(){
    $container.picsLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.box',
        isAnimated : true,
        animationOptions: { duration: 800 }
        }); 
    }); 
}); 

// MouseOver Events
$('.box').hover(function(){
    $('img', this).animate({"opacity": ".8"}, "slow");
    },
function(){
    $('img', this).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
```

Comment: Did you include the library for `picsLoaded `? and where?

Comment: Don't know what it is... but i am using to apply things after the pictures are fully loaded

Comment: am using the one from here with some change 

http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/images.html

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing variable name with jquery's $... perhaps you want to give the variable name as only container and then later do $(container).picsLoaded...